# Open new transaction in Spring Batch - @AfterJob event?

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch framework and I was wondering if, is it possible to open a new transaction in `@AfterStep` or `@AfterJob` event?

I am seeing that when I try to execute a SQL query inside these events, the current transaction is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to annotate your method with a @Transactional annotation and using REQUIRES_NEW ?